# Cannot load an image from internet with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a little problem, actually I'm trying to display this url

https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/wakfu/portal/game/item/115/13620723.png

in an ImageView but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

I tried with this url https://gluonhq.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/phones-v3-small@2x.png

and it works perfectly fine.

Here's the code :

FXML part :

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>

<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">

    <ImageView fitWidth="50" fitHeight="50">
          <Image url="https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/wakfu/portal/game/item/115/13620723.png"/>
    </ImageView>

</GridPane>
```

Java part :

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Note : I use JavaFX with JDK 8

Comment: Try with HTTP, not HTTPS

Comment: that redirects to https

Comment: I tried, it changes nothing :/

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem with JavaFX 11.0.2. Try listening to the `Image.exception` property to see if you get any errors.

Comment: I tried with JavaFX 11.0.2, for some reasons it works fine.